# AFAmazonS3Manager acceptable content-types for images

Tags: ios, iphone, image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AFAmazonS3Manager in order to manage images. I've uploaded a test image named test.jpg into my bucket. However, when executing the below code, I get a code -1016 failure for unacceptable content-types. How do I add image/jpeg as an acceptable content-type?

```
s3Manager.requestSerializer.region = AFAmazonS3USWest1Region;
s3Manager.requestSerializer.bucket = @"BUCKET_NAME";

[s3Manager getObjectWithPath:@"/test.jpg" progress:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    NSLog(@"%u", bytesRead);
} success:^(id responseObject, NSData *responseData) {
    NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops -- figured it out. Had to add a responseSerializer as shown below:

```
s3Manager.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
```